# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am fairly new here. We are trying to get an existing php application run on my windows machine. I have installed xampp and mongodb on my machine. While trying to run the application this is the error i have been getting. I have also made sure to have the mongodb.so extension added to the php.ini file. Please guide me

Using Verion php 7.2.24

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJECT\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php:87
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ PROJECT\header.php(5):
>   MongoDB\Client->__construct('mongodb+srv://r...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\
>   PROJECT\index.php(3): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\ PROJECT\vendor\mongodb\mongodb\src\Client.php on
>   line 87

Comment: Have you tried all instructions here? https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.installation.windows.php

Comment: Could you please show a code, where you create new instance MongoDB\Driver\Manager?

Comment: It's help you - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mongodb.installation.pecl.php

Comment: Re-doing the process on this page helped "https://learnedia.com/install-mongodb-configure-php-xampp-windows/ " . Thank you everyone.